# Equivalent to TSQL " IN(subSelect) " in ENTITY FRAMEWORK / LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have an SQL-Statement that I have to transfer to Entity Framework:

```
select * from logbuch where institutionid = @id OR userid IN (SELECT id from benutzerkonto where institution_id = @id)
```

I have as EntityFramework:

```
context.logbuch.Where(x => x.institutionid == int.Parse(benutzerkontoID) || x.userid ???INSIDE SUBSELECT???).ToList();
```

I am very new in EF & LINQ and I don't know how it is possiple to integrate the subselect-condition right side of OR.

Can someone help me realising this in a EntityFramework-Query?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `|| context,benutzerkonto.Where(b => b.institution_id ==  int.Parse(benutzerkontoID).Select(b => b.id).Contains(x.userid) `

Comment: Try following : context.logbuch.Select(x => x.institutionid == int.Parse(benutzerkontoID) || context.benutzerkonto.Where(y => y.institution_id ==  x.institutionid).FirstOrDefault()).ToList()

Comment: @sTrenat: Thank you, after repairing one missing bracket, its working!

Comment: @comidos, FYI: the question is not on EF, rather it is on LINQ/Lambda expressions.

Comment: @jdweng: I tried this too, but didn't get it running! Operator isn't accepted for this comparison (bool <=> object)

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage: Sorry, like i said, i am very new in this part!

Comment: context.logbuch.Select(x => (x.institutionid == int.Parse(benutzerkontoID))? x : context.benutzerkonto.Where(y => y.institution_id == x.institutionid)).ToList()

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you. Basically define sub-select as separate query variable and use `Contains`.